# check box to change value of drop down

Tags: pdf

I am trying to make out work order PDF more automated.

So for example I am trying to get the following boxes to do this.

Dropdown 6 if Aluminium or Cast Aluminium or Stainless Steel or Galvanised is selected then Check Box 32 is checked and Dropdown34 to show "Etch HMG St3000"

Is there a template we can use for this we have several conditions for various substrates as to regular things that happen on the word order which we can do but are stuck getting the dropdowns to work?

I mean a peice of javscript written that shows me what i need to do, so i can modify this in order to get the other parts working, its the same principal for the other peices of the work order just different check boxes and drop downs.

Comment: What do you mean by "a template"?

Comment: I mean a peice of javscript written that shows me what i need to do, so i can modify this in order to get the other parts working, its the same principal for the other peices of the work order just different check boxes and drop downs.

Comment: Please add all details to your question by editing it

Comment: Added further detaila to the questions, is there naything else you need as not to sure what else you would need?